Proving $\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n-j}\sum\limits_{q=0}^j\binom{n-j}p\binom jq\binom{n-j-p+q}{b-p}\binom{j+p-q}{a-b+p}{(-1)}^{b-p+q}=\delta_{j,a}\binom nb$
Given $n,j,a,b$, show that
$$
\sum_{p=0}^{n-j} \sum_{q=0}^j \binom{n-j}{p} \binom{j}{q} \binom{n-j-p+q}{b-p} \binom{j+p-q}{a-b+p} (-1)^{b-p+q} = \begin{cases}
\binom{n}{b} & \text{ if } j=a \\
0 & \text{ if } j \neq a 
\end{cases}
$$

This sum came up while trying to solve this question. I have tried writing the binomial coefficient with coefficient extraction from the generating function and then simplifying but should we write both the two last ones or what?

Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see meta.

Why the downvotes?! If it's for lack of efforts in trying, see that I have now even managed to solve it myself. Well, it's a little bit hazy still because using 2 variable countour integration but since the out come is just plainly a binomial series of sort and we know its coefficients, I think it's clear.

(+1) Presumably because the report of your first attempt ("I have tried [...] or what?") is not detailed enough.

This is just a verification of OPs calculation using the coefficient of operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^n
\end{align*}
We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{p=0}^{n-j}}\,&\color{blue}{\sum_{q=0}^j\binom{n-j}{p}\binom{j}{q}
\binom{n-j-p+q}{b-p}\binom{j+p-q}{a-b+p}(-1)^{b-p+q}}\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{n-j}\sum_{q=0}^j\binom{n-j}{p}\binom{j}{q}
\binom{n-j-p-q}{b-p}\binom{p+q}{a-b+p}(-1)^{b-p+j-q}\tag{$q\to j-q$}\\
&=(-1)^{b+j}\sum_{p=0}^{n-j}\binom{n-j}{p}\sum_{q=0}^j\binom{j}{q}[z^{b-p}](1+z)^{n-p-q}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdot[w^{a-b+p}](1+w)^{p+q}(-1)^{p+q}\\
&=(-1)^{b+j}[z^b](1+z)^n[w^{a-b}]\sum_{p=0}^{n-j}\binom{n-j}{b}\left(-\frac{z(1+w)}{w(1+z)}\right)^p\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdot\sum_{q=0}^j\binom{j}{q}\left(-\frac{1+w}{1+z}\right)^q\\
&=(-1)^{b+j}[z^b](1+z)^n[w^{a-b}]\left(1-\frac{z(1+w)}{w(1+z)}\right)^{n-j}\left(1-\frac{1+w}{1+z}\right)^j\\
&=(-1)^{b+j}[z^b](1+z)^n[w^{a-b}]\left(\frac{w-z}{w(1+z)}\right)^{n-j}\left(\frac{z-w}{1+z}\right)^j\\
&=(-1)^b[z^b][w^{a-b+n-j}](w-z)^n\\
&=[w^{a-b+n-j}]\binom{n}{b}w^{n-b}\\
&=\binom{n}{b}[w^{a-j}]1\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n}{b}\delta_{a,j}}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

It was helpful that you showed the FPS approach. (+1).

@MarkoRiedel: Thank you very much, Marko :-)

I managed to do it with the Egorychev method.
Let's write
$$
\binom{n-j-p+q}{b-p} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n-j-p+q}}{z^{b-p+1}} dz
$$
and
$$
\binom{j+p-q}{a-b+p} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\delta} \frac{(1+w)^{j+p-q}}{w^{a-b+p+1}} dw
$$
to turn the sum into
$$
\frac{1}{(2 \pi i)^2} \int_z \int_w
\left( \sum_p \binom{n-j}{p} \frac{(1+z)^{-p}(1+w)^p}{(-z)^{-p}w^p} \right)
\left( \sum_q \binom{j}{q} \left(-\frac{1+z}{1+w}\right)^{q} \right) \frac{(1+z)^{n-j}(1+w)^{j}}{z^{b+1}w^{a-b+1}} (-1)^b dw dz
\\=
\frac{1}{(2 \pi i)^2} \int_z \int_w
\left( 1- \frac{z(1+w)}{w(1+z)} \right)^{n-j} \left( 1- \frac{1+z}{1+w} \right)^{j} \frac{(1+z)^{n-j}(1+w)^{j}}{z^{b+1}w^{a-b+1}} (-1)^b dw dz
\\=
\frac{1}{(2 \pi i)^2} \int_z \int_w (w-z)^n \frac{(-1)^b}{z^{b+1}w^{n-b+a-j+1}} dw dz
$$
And expanding $(w-z)^n$ we see that the coefficient of $z^b w^{n-b + a-j}$ is $(-1)^b \binom{n}{b}$ iff $a-j=0$.

Can you please check the first line of the last block, I think in the first denominator you want $(-1)^p z^{-p}.$ Also you lost a factor of $(-1)^b$ which you need to conclude. Luckily all your sums are finite so you don't have to worry about convergence which would otherwise be considered essential. Everything can in fact be done using formal power series.

@MarkoRiedel Thanks, fixed it.
